# SharePoint Accessing Site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm so sorry if this question is very basic but I'm very new to SharePoint. I only explored SharePoint Office 365 (SharePoint Online) so I'm not familiar with the server-side of it. I'm using SharePoint 2010. I've installed it in a server along with SQL Server 2008 R2 (so this server is the SharePoint server and the database server). I've configured it as a standalone (which is I'm not sure if right). I have another server for Active Directory Users and the SharePoint/Database server is a member of it's domain. How can I add users from Active Directory to be able to access the Central Administration and the site I'm going to build with the SharePoint/Database server? Please help me as I'm a beginner here. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Login using the user which you used to install the Sharepoint 2010.

It will become your System Account . Then add other AD users to the CA site. and provide them appropriate permissions as per your requirements

Also add ad users to the site collection administrators for the other site you want to access .

Add them as a Site collection administrators for that site from Central administration

then log into that site :- goto site actions > site setting > People and Group

Here you can add the users in a group from AD users and provide them appropriate permissions